# use dev_appserver.py for specific file in a directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cmd

In order to start Google app engine through the cmd i use: `dev_appserver.py --port=8080`, but i can't figure how does it pick a file to run from the current directory.
My question is, is there an argument specifying a file to run in the server from all possible files in the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev_appserver doesn't "run a file" at all. It launches the GAE dev environment, and routes requests using the paths defined in app.yaml just like the production version.

If you need to route your requests to a specific Python file, you should define that in app.yaml.